# How to deploy a trigger word detection with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on the "trigger word detection" model, and I decided to deploy the model to my phone.

The input shape of the model is `(None, 5511, 101)`.
The output shape is `(None, 1375, 1)`.

But in a real deployed App, the model can't get the 5511 timesteps all at once, instead the audio frame produced by the sensor of the phone is one by one.

How can I feed this pieces of data to the model one by one and get the output at each timestep?

The model is a recurrent one.  But the "model.predict()" takes a first parameter of (None,5511,101), and what I intend to do is

```
output = []
for i in range(5511): 
    a = model.func(i, (None,1,101))
    output.append(a)
```

structure of the model:

[image: structure of the model]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by making the timesteps axis dynamic. In other words, when you define the model, the number of timesteps should be set to `None`. Here is an example illustrating how it would work for a simplified version of your model:

```
from keras.layers import GRU, Input, Conv1D
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

x = Input(shape=(None, 101))
h = Conv1D(196, 15, strides=4)(x)
h = GRU(1, return_sequences=True)(h)
model = Model(x, h)


# The model works for the original number of timesteps (5511)
batch_size = 2
out = model.predict(np.random.rand(batch_size, 5511, 101))
print(out.shape)


# ... but also for fewer timesteps (say 32)
out = model.predict(np.random.rand(batch_size, 32, 101))
print(out.shape)


# However, it will not work if timesteps < Conv1D filter_size (15)!
out = model.predict(np.random.rand(batch_size, 14, 101))
print(out.shape)
```

Note, however, that you will not be able to feed less than 15 timesteps (dimension of the Conv1D filters) unless you pad the input sequences to 15.

Answer (score 1):

You should either change your model in a recurrent one where you can feed pieces of data one at a time or you should think about changing the model and using something that works on (overlapping) windows in time, where you apply the model every few pieces of data and get a partial output.

Still depending on the model you might get the output you want only at the end. You should design it accordingly.

Here is an example: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/09/speech-recognition-deepspeech/

Comment: The model is a recurrent one.  But the "model.predict()" takes an first parameter (None,5511,101), and what I tend to do is " for i in range(5511): model.predict(i, (None,1,101))"

Comment: No your model is not a fully recurrent network. You have a big Conv1D in from of everything and you cannot compute it a piece at a time. You should drop vanilla Keras and do something similar to what they suggest in the link I sent you.

Comment: Maybe do not use 1 single sample at a time. Take a window of samples and use a recurrent model that has a conv1D on the window and proceed with that.

Answer (score 1):

For passing inputs step by step, you need recurrent layers with `stateful=True`.

The convolutional layer will certainly prevent you from achieving what you want. Either you remove it or you pass inputs in groups of 15 steps (where 15 is your kernel size for the convolution).

You would need to coordinate these 15 steps with stride 4, and might need a padding. If I may suggest, to avoid mathematical difficulties, you could use `kernel_size=16`, `stride=4` and `input_steps = 5512`, this is a multiple of `4` which is your stride value. (This will avoid padding and allow easier calculations), and your output steps will be 1375 perfectly round.

Then your model would be like:

```
inputs = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size,None, 101)) #where you will always use input shapes of (batch_size, 16, 101)
out = Conv1D(196, 16, strides=4)(inputs)
...
...
out = GRU(..., stateful=True)(out)
...
out = GRU(..., stateful=True)(out)
...
...

model = Model(inputs, out)
```

It's necessary to have a fixed batch size with a `stateful=True` model. It can be 1, but for optimizing your processing speed, if you have more than one sequence to process in parallel (and independently from each other), use a bigger batch size.

For working it step by step, you need, first of all, to reset states (whenever you use a `stateful=True` model, you need to keep resetting states every time you are going to feed a new sequence or a new batch of parallel sequences).

So:

```
#will start a new batch containing a number of sequences equal to batch_size:
model.reset_states()

#received 16 steps from batch_size sequences:
steps = an_array_shaped((batch_size, 16, 101))

#for training 
model.train_on_batch(steps, something_for_y_shaped((batch_size, 1, 1)), ...)
    #I don't recommend to train like this because of the batch normalizations    
    #If you can train the entire length at once, do it.    
    #never forget: for full length training, you would need model.reset_states() every batch. 

#for predicting:
predictions = model.predict_on_batch(steps, ...)

#received 4 new steps from X sequences:
steps = np.concatenate([steps[:,4:], new_steps], axis=1)

#these new steps belong to the "same" batch_size sequences! Don't call reset states!
#repeat one of the above for training or predicting
new_predictions = model.predict_on_batch(steps, ...)
predictions = np.concatenate([predictions, new_predictions], axis=1)

#keep repeating this loop until you reach the last step

Finally, when you reached the last step, for safety, call `model.reset_states()` again, everything that you input will be "new" sequences, not new "steps" or the previous sequences. 

------------

# Training hint

If you are able to train with the full sequences (not step by step), use a `stateful=False` model, train normally with `model.fit(...)`, later you recreate the model exactly, but using `stateful=True`, copy the weights with `new_model.set_weights(old_model.get_weights())`, and use the new model for predicting like above.
```

Comment: Thanks for your instructive answer!  that's exactly what I intend to figure out.   I have an additional question:  can this trained model work in  "tensorflow lite" in an android?

Comment: because I didn't find a api in tf lite of android  alike with the "reset_states",   and also supportion with dynamic rnn of tf like is underdeveloped,   I suppose this solution can't work in android.

Comment: I have tested a simple model with only one layer of lstm with "stateful=True" in my android.  Though the whole procedure haven't raised an exception, the output in tf lite was different with the original model in python.

Comment: In python,  the output of the model was ten random numbers, instead the output in tf lite was ten identical number.